# out of the reach or out of reach

Tags: articles

I have seen the following on different products.

1. Keep out of the reach of children.
2. Keep out of reach of children.

What is the difference between those two statements?

Comment: Largely nothing. There may be dialect differences as to which form a person would prefer, but both forms are common.

Comment: "out of reach" is a known epression - anyway - try google too http://www.antimoon.com/forum/t6950.htm

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: for one, you need an extra "of"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a prepositional phrase:

*The object is out of reach.*

indicates the object cannot be "reached" (touched, for example).

Using *the* in conjunction with a propositional phrase is colloquially used to reference *moving* an object to an "out of reach" position:

*Move the knife out of the reach of the small child!*

Comment: Not just moving. The moving bit is not relevant to the definite article—it’s just that when you add the prepositional phrase, you’re talking about _someone’s_ reach, which is a more _specific_ reach than just ‘reach’ in general, and thus definite. Similarly, something can get _out of hand_, but it is _out of **the** hands of [someone]_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good comment, I will remove"moving"